# How can to get distinct data of all the columns in a table in spearte result set in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have created a Stored Procedure to get distinct data of all the columns. But I have to Specify each column name of the respective table.

Bur I don't want to specify each column name of the table and get the distinct data of all the columnn in separte result set.

```
+----+------+---------+-----------+
| Id | name | Address |   City    |
+----+------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | A    | Max     | Rajasthan |
|  2 | A    | Min     | Delhi     |
|  1 | A    | Max     | Rajathan  |
|  1 | A    | Min     | UP        |
+----+------+---------+-----------+
```

This is the code of my Stored Procedure for getting different result set of each column

```
create proc sp_task1  @table varchar(20)
as
begin
exec('
select distinct id FROM ' +@table+'
')
exec('
select distinct name FROM ' +@table+'
')
exec('
select distinct address FROM ' +@table+'
')
exec('
select distinct city FROM ' +@table+'
')
end
exec sp_task1 @table = 'table1'
```

This is what I get in result when I Execute the SP.

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+

+------+
| name |
+------+
| A    |
+------+


+---------+
| Address |
+---------+
| Max     |
| Min     |
+---------+


+-----------+
|   city    |
+-----------+
| Rajasthan |
| Delhi     |
+-----------+
```

Now, I want to do this dynamically without specifying the column names.

Please give me any kind of help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query to do this.

**TEST SETUP**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test(id int, name varchar(20), city varchar(20));

INSERT INTO Test
values(1,'abc','chennai'),
(2,'abc','bangalore');
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GetDistinct(@TableName SYSNAME,@TableSchema SYSNAME )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = (
    SELECT 'SELECT  DISTINCT ' + 
    Column_Name + 
           ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(Table_Name) + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10) + 'GO'+CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND table_schema = @TableSchema      
    FOR XML PATH(''), Type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')

    --PRINT @SQL

    EXECUTE (@SQL)
END
```

**Execute procedure**

```sql
EXEC USP_GetDistinct @TableName='Test', @TableSchema='dbo'
```

**Result set**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+

+------+
| name |
+------+
| abc  |
+------+


+-----------+
|   city    |
+-----------+
| bangalore |
| chennai   |
+-----------+
```

Comment: welcome. Please mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future.

Comment: In Sql Server 2017 and later you can use STRING_AGG instead of the XML PATH technique

Comment: @Venkataraman R, can you please explain me what have you done in this Stored Procedure.

Comment: I am reading the list of columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table and then generating dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: FOR XML Path is a way to generate concatenation of values. you can find samples online about this. CHAR(13), CHAR(10) are for carriage return, line feed. You can search about them online. Search engines are your best friend to learn about them.

Comment: Ok I will see this adn Thank You